# jquery use json_encoded array from AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I'm just trying to spit the elements of an array into seperate input fields on a form via jquery's AJAX.

Heres my javascript code:

```
        $('#based').change(function() { 
        if ($(this).val().length > 0)
        {           
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajax.php",
                data: "id="+$(this).val(),
                success: function(data){
                    if (data != 'error')
                    {                       
                        $('#keyword').val(data[2]);
                        $('#keyword_slug').val(data[3]);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Heres my PHP code for 'ajax.php':

```
$sql = mysql_query("select * from `keywords` where `id`='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id'])."'");

if (mysql_num_rows($sql) == 0)
{
    echo 'error';
}
else
{
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
    {
        foreach ($row as $k => $v)
            $data[] = $v;
    }

    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Its not working. What do I do here? I've looked into serializeArray but can't get anything to work properly.

Comment: What does your returning array look like?

Comment: Can you print the length of the data array on the server and also on the client ?

Comment: what is your POST ? what exactly script is returned ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need `dataType: 'json'` if you are expecting JSON back.

Otherwise jQuery has to guess, and if you are not sending the Content Type `application/json`, it may guess wrong.

Comment: If that's the issue, it's better to do this in PHP and set the `Content-Type` header to `JSON`

Comment: @cwolves I hope you mean `application/json`. I also prefer to explicitly state the return type.

Comment: setting the dataType worked perfectly :). one more problem - one of the fields is a textarea and this doesn't seem to be passing linebreaks "\n"

Comment: @scarhand You may better off asking a new question with that :) [Worked for me with a string](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/7aC44/).